# PHP/MySQL group news/archives by year then month

Tags: php, mysql

I've got some code which outputs a news archive sidebar. It all works very well apart from the fact that it doesn't split the months by year properly. Rather than assigning the relevant month to its year, all months are being shown for all years! Very frustrating! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM isnews WHERE active = '1' ORDER BY YEAR(date) DESC, MONTH(date) DESC";
$resultSet = mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_num_rows($resultSet)){
    $newsArray = array();

    echo '<ul>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<li><strong>Press releases:</strong></li>' . PHP_EOL;                                            

    while ($newsResult = mysql_fetch_array($resultSet)){ 
        $newDate =  $newsResult['date'] ;   
        $timePeriod = date('F  Y ',strtotime($newDate));
        $timePeriodY = date('Y',strtotime($timePeriod));
        $timePeriodM = date('F',strtotime($timePeriod));                                          

        if (!isset($newsArray[$timePeriod])){
              $newsArray[$timePeriod] = array();
        }           
        $newsArray[$timePeriod][] = $newsResult;                                      
    }                                         

    //by year
    foreach ($newsArray as $timePeriod => $newsItems){
        $timePeriodY = date('Y',strtotime($timePeriod));
        echo '<li><strong>' . $timePeriodY . '</strong>' . PHP_EOL;  
        echo '<ul>' . PHP_EOL;

        //by month
        foreach ($newsArray as $timePeriod => $newsItems){
            echo '<li><strong>' . $timePeriod . '</strong>' . PHP_EOL;  
            echo '<ul>' . PHP_EOL;                                

            //news items
            foreach ($newsItems as $item){
                echo '<li>';
                echo '<a href="'.$wwwUrl.'press-releases/'.$item["id"].'/'.$item["title"].'.php">'.$item["title"].'</a>';
                echo '</li>' . PHP_EOL;
            }     

            //end by month
            echo '</ul>' . PHP_EOL; 
            echo '</li>' . PHP_EOL;                   
        }

        //end by year
        echo '</ul>' . PHP_EOL; 
        echo '</li>' . PHP_EOL;                   
    }

    echo '<li>&nbsp;</li>' . PHP_EOL;   
    echo '</ul>' . PHP_EOL; 
} else {
    echo 'We currently have no press releases available';
}
```

Many thanks in advance
S

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be using  :

```
ORDER BY abc, xyz DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Why You dont just Use

```
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're printing, why are you iterating through the `$newsArray` twice (when you have the foreach within foreach)?

Maybe I'm missing something, but basically for every month/year in the array you are printing all the news for all the months/years. Keeping just the inner foreach should solve the problem.